# 'babel-eslint' was not found. Error: ESLint configuration of processor in '.eslintrc.json#overrides[0]' is invalid

Tags: babeljs, lint, babel-eslint

I have a eslint config file `.eslintrc.json` (could be .eslintrc) like this:

```
{  
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "es6": true
  },
  "extends": [
      "eslint:recommended",
      "plugin:react/recommended",
      "plugin:@typescript-eslint/eslint-recommended",
      "airbnb-typescript-prettier"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "@typescript-eslint"
  ],
  "globals": {
      "Atomics": "readonly",
      "SharedArrayBuffer": "readonly"
  },
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "parserOptions": {
      "ecmaFeatures": {
          "jsx": true
      },
      "ecmaVersion": 2018,
      "sourceType": "module"
  },
  "overrides": [
    {
        "files": ["*.js", "*.jsx"],
        "processor": "babel-eslint"
    }
  ],
  "rules": {
    "react/prop-types": 0,
    "semi": ["error", "never"]
  }
}
```

and I got a persistent error

```
Error: ESLint configuration of processor in '.eslintrc.json#overrides[0]' is invalid: 'babel-eslint' was not found
```

Answer (score 1):

Although official [eslint site](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring) suggest this configuration, you need to use `parser` property in the `overrides` instead of `processor` such as the following:

```
...
  "overrides": [
  {
    "files": ["*.js", "*.jsx"],
    "parser": "babel-eslint"
  }
],
...
```

With this change everything works pretty well.